# Delete PDF made in laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I have created a PDF in Laravel 5 by Laravel-dompdf.

```
     $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html)
          ->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')
          ->setWarnings(false)
          ->save('documents/f_'.$pdf_name.'.pdf');
          //$pdf->download('deposit.pdf');
```

My question is, How can I delete it now?
I didn´t find nothing in the documentation.

Comment: Really? Nothing in the PHP documentation at all?
 https://www.google.com/search?q=delete+file+php

Comment: With  Laravel 5 by Laravel-dompdf no.

Comment: Has nothing to do with Laravel 5 or dompdf. You created a file and need to delete it. PHP has that built in.